# How to add text hovers for generic eclipse editor- generic text hover for all text editors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I want to display a text hover functionality in `Eclipse` editors without contributing a new editor. That means my hover functionality shall work on CDT editor ,JDT editor (java editor) and all other text editors.Is their any generic extension point is present for this purpose ? I know, for `java` editor `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEdit` or TextHovers is there and for CDT editor `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.textHovers` is there. But I want the hover shall work in all type of editors. is there any `extension point` present for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextHover extension point and then write a class that implements ITextHover which allows you to specify an IRegion for areas where the hover should be displaye dand then another method for displaying hover text based in cursor position.